# How to remove onclick button appearing on popup - CSS & JS Related

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnuQG.png)`popup` This image shows the popup window appearing on button click i.e "share". I want to remove that button so that it should not appear on the window that opens on click.[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3sS2.png)`

```
<div class="view-list"> 
    <h3><b>Share</b></h3>

                    <div class="share-transcript">
                        <!--input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Share transcript(s) with "-->
                        <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary otp-single-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" value="share">
                    </div>
</div>
 <h4 class="modal-title">OTP</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="form-block">
      <form name="frm_stuff">
      <div class="cehck-box-btn">
         <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="checkbox1" name="stuff_type" class="styled" value="university" type="radio">
                        <label for="checkbox1">
                            University
                        </label>
                    </div>

                         <div class="checkbox">
                         <input type='hidden' name="login_email" id="login_email" value="<?php echo $user_mail_stuff; ?>" />
                        <input id="checkbox2" name="stuff_type" class="styled" value="corporate" type="radio">
                        <label for="checkbox2">
                            Corporate
                        </label>
                    </div>
      </div>
      <span id="email_error"></span>
      <input name="OTPemail_stuff" id="OTPemail_stuff" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email id" class="form-control" />
      <input name="" class="OTP_submit_stuff" type="button" value="SEND" />
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>`



 .acadview-popup {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .acadview-popup.in {
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .otp-single-btn {
        background: none;
        color: #11abc7;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999999;
    }
    .otp-single-btn:hover, .otp-single-btn:focus {
        background: none;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .acadview-popup .close {
        background: #04accb;
        width: 34px;
        height: 33px;
        color: #fff;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        right: -11px;
        top: -6px;
    }
    .acadview-popup .close span {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
    .acadview-popup .modal-header {
        background: url(../images/title-bg.png) repeat-x left top;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px 0;
    }
    .acadview-popup .modal-header .modal-title {
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .acadview-popup .modal-sm {
        width: 470px;
        z-index:9999;
    }
    .acadview-popup .modal-content {
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .form-block {
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .form-block input[type="text"] {
        min-height: 54px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    .form-block input[type="send"], .form-block input[type="button"] {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 450px;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #04accb 0%, #0bc2e4 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 90deg, color-stop(0%, #04accb), color-stop(100%, #0bc2e4));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #04accb 0%, #0bc2e4 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #04accb 0%, #0bc2e4 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #04accb 0%, #0bc2e4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#04accb', endColorstr='#0bc2e4', GradientType='0');
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, #04accb 0%, #0bc2e4 100%);
        border: none;
        margin-top: 18px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 300;
        min-height: 54px;
        line-height: 54px;
    }
    .form-block input[type="share"]:hover, .form-block input[type="button"]:hover {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #0bc2e4 0%, #04accb 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 90deg, color-stop(0%, #0bc2e4), color-stop(100%, #04accb));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #0bc2e4 0%, #04accb 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #0bc2e4 0%, #04accb 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #0bc2e4 0%, #04accb 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0bc2e4', endColorstr='#04accb', GradientType='0');
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0bc2e4 0%, #04accb 100%);
    }
```

Comment: Show use your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Here is the code! I have edited it. Please check it.

Comment: If you put your code in `JsFiddle` and post a link to there you will get a better answer. From what I see you need to either hide or keep the button behind the modal, both are possible using either `CSS` or `JavaScript` (`jQuery`). It depends on what you prefer and partially on what your CSS/JS looks like.

Comment: Yes you got it right. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: As I wrote - your current code is still lacking a lot of information - how your CSS looks, do you use some `JS` libraries and if yes - which? Judging from your rating I guess you are new to StackOverflow so you may not be aware bu actually if you put a bit more effort and recreate the problem let's say here- https://jsfiddle.net/ then it will be a lot more easier and interesting for people to play around and offer you solutions. And since the actual part that I would like to see is missing I will just throw you two suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at `z-index` and what it does, it may be sufficient for your case. If not you gonna have to handle the button click event and the close event of the popup in order to manipulate the button. The approach depends on what is your expectation. If you just want the button in the background just look at what `z-index` and maybe write another question how to use it if you can't handle it yourself.

Comment: Can you add your relevant css to your post as well?

Comment: Yes i added CSS code. Please check it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete or/and incorrect. However I think you overcomplicate something pretty basic. Here is something basic that I did just to get you going. I think, this is pretty much the standard approach when it comes to modals - https://jsfiddle.net/mx199vqh/ just have to apply the neccessary styles.

Comment: I have added only that code which is relevant to discribe what i want to do. But anyways i got a bit clue from what you shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the button altogether you can either remove or comment this part of the code out.

```
<div class="share-transcript">
   <!--input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Share transcript(s) with "-->
   <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary otp-single-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" value="share">
</div>
```

Or in your style sheet you can display it none.

Comment: But display it none will not display button. I don't want that. I want that when the button is clicked pop up which is showing will continue showing but button is also shown on that.

Comment: So you want the "Share" button to show, but would like it in a different spot?

Comment: Yes i want the share to show. But not on the popup window. I guess you are getting my point. Just see the # '1 popup' image attached.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your button's z-index value lower than your popup's z-index. You've set the z-index value of acadview-popup element 9999, which is lower than the z-index of button "share". Thus, the button will be placed over the popup.